# Show web pages randomly using percentage

Tags: ruby

I have 3 web pages variation (page A, page B, page C), I would like to show these page randomly like the following :

page A : 30%

page B : 50%

page c : 20%

How I can do that using ruby

Comment: Pick a random number between 1 and 10 and show the appropriate page?

Comment: @DaveNewton but I would like to show a page switch the percentage, page A : 30% of the time, page B : 50% of the time which means that page B will show up more times than page A

Comment: Right. So pick a random number between 1 and 10. 0, 1, 2 show A. 3, 4 show C. Otherwise show C. Not sure what the difficulty is.

Comment: @DaveNewton will that ensure that these pages show up using these percentages ? I am not very good on math, also I am not sure how random() function works! thanks

Comment: You can do something like this: `case rand(10); when 0..2; <display A>; when 3..7; <display B>; else; <display C>;; end`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What Dave Newton is saying:

```
random = rand(10)

if random < 5 # 50% of the time 0,1,2,3 or 4 will be randomly chosen
  # Open B
elsif random < 8 # 30% of the time 5,6 or 7 will be randomly chosen
  # Open A
else # 20% of the time 8 or 9 will be randomly chosen
  # Open C
end
```